# How to set default value of WiX Msi install path in the ui to Program Files?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I have created a WiX installer MSI. When i run the msi, the installation path is asked for in the UI. Currently it loads the drive containing most of the free space. How can I set it to be at program files folder all the time? I tried the below line but it didn't work.

```
 <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="C:\\Program Files\" />
```

Below is the error I get for the above element.

```
 The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , ,
```

How can I make the UI load C:\Program Files as the default location all the time? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make use of the already defined [windows installer properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx) which are always defined by Windows Installer (caveat on some 64-bit only properties). In this case specifically the [ProgramFilesFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370881(v=vs.85).aspx)

Try using a directory definition like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyProductFolder" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And then, following the same principal as this quick tutorial page about [using WixUI_InstallDir](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html)

You'll want to do

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
```

Now when you show the UI page that lets you change the install location it should have the value `C:\Program File\MyProductFolder`

As a side-note, I would avoid making the install location *just* C:\Program Files because that may cause you to add a ton of extraneous files to this location where they should instead be contained in a product/program folder.

You should also never try to hardcode a path like "C:\Program Files\". In this specific case I can give you two quick examples why not to. There is no guarantee that the user is using the C:\ drive as their main drive or even uses a C:\ drive at all (one anecdote of this [here](http://ask-leo.com/i_have_no_c_drive_but_some_programs_insist_on_it_what_can_i_do.html)). Another issue is (for 32-bit installs) on a 32-bit machine you'll want to install into the Program Files location but on a 64-bit machine you'll want to install into the "Program Files (x86)" location.